# Toggle class of search input on hover of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I want to add a class to the search box when I hover over the i element then remove the classes added when I hover out.

```
 <li><input id="search" type="text" class="search-box-hidden"  placeholder="Enter Your Keywords..."> <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-lg"></i></li>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".fa.fa-search-plus.fa-lg").hover(
function(){ $(".search-box-hidden").toggleClass("search-box-shown") });
});
```

I edited my code. Basically when I hover over the icon from Font Awesome, it triggers the class that shows the search box and when I over out the search box will go back to the hidden class.

LIKE SO:
http://s27.postimg.org/pq2zeetw3/preview.jpg

With this code, it still does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: perhaps `$("fa.fa-search-plus.fa-lg")` should be `$(".fa.fa-search-plus.fa-lg")` ... missing the first '.' in the selector

Comment: do you want to add class at first hover and then remove on second and so on? or just toggle it on hover?

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's not working

Comment: @Ted I missed that! I added but still not working.

Comment: there is a selector problem(missing `.` as already pointed out)... seee http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/U3kha/2/

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/v4FSh/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're missing `.` to target class `fa`, it should be:

```
$(".fa.fa-search-plus.fa-lg").hover(
// ^ here ----
```

Secondly, if you want to only target the `input` which is the previous sibling of your icon, then use:

```
$(".fa.fa-search-plus.fa-lg").hover(
function () {
    $(this).prev().addClass("search-box")
},
function () {
    $(this).prev().removeClass("search-box")
})
```

or you can use `toggleClass()` instead of add and remove here:

```
$("fa.fa-search-plus.fa-lg").hover(function() {
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('search-box');
});
```

Comment: Still need the '.' before 'fa' in the selector

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#ElementToTriggerHover").hover(function(){
      $("#ElementToSwitchClass").toggleClass("TheClassYouWantToToggle");
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you have added three classes to your < i > not to input box and

second you are using all them at once seem to represent a hierarchy, so I think using any one of them would be enough.

also Instead of add and then removing in row, use `toggleClass`.

html :

```
  <li>
     <input id="search" type="text" class="hidden" placeholder="Enter Your 
      Keywords...">
     <i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-lg"></i>
  </li>
```

js:

```
$(".fa-search-plus").hover(
   function(){ $(".hidden").toggleClass("search-box") });
```

**OR**

just simply use css `:hover` selecter as

```
.fa-search-plus:hover{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is missing a . at the beginning. Make sure you are doing it after DOM load and that you are loading jQuery on the page properly.

```
$(function() {
    $(".fa.fa-search-plus.fa-lg").hover(
       function(){ 
           $(".hidden").addClass("search-box");
       },
       function(){ 
           $(".hidden").removeClass("search-box");
       }
    );
});
```

EDIT:
Mockup, but with animation (not show/hide):
http://jsfiddle.net/v4FSh/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with CSS.

I made a simple <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/VpWzd/)</kbd> using `hover` and `transition`.

Take a look. Maybe it helps.